# Sum rows in data frame based on two columns

Tags: r

I would like to add the values of one column grouping them by two columns. I found how to do this on one column, but could not figure out how to do this on two columns.
For example if I have the following data frame:

```
x=c("a","a", "b", "b","c", "c","a","a","b","b","c","c", "a", "a","b","b", "c", "c") 
y=c(1:18) 
q=c("M","M","M", "M","M","M","W","W","W","W","W","W","F","F","F","F","F","F")
df<-data.frame(x,y,q)
```

I would like to add the values in y column across x and q, so that I have a new data frame like this one

```
x=c("a","a", "b", "b","c", "c","a","a","b","b","c","c", "a", "a","b","b", "c", "c") 
y=c(3,7,11,15,19,23,27,31,35) 
q=c("M","M","M","W","W","W","F","F","F")
d<-data.frame(x,y,q)
```

Comment: `aggregate(y~x+q, df, sum)`

Comment: Or with the `dplyr` package: `df %>% group_by(x,q) %>% summarise(ySum = sum(y))`.

Comment: Thanks, both. I tried 'aggregate' and it worked. Will try the second one just for fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options:

**1:** Base R

```
aggregate(y ~ x + q, df, sum)
```

**2:** data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(sumy = sum(y)), by = .(x, q)]

# when you want to summarise several columns:
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(x, q)]
```

**3:** dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(x, q) %>% summarise(sumy = sum(y))

# when you want to summarise several columns:
df %>% group_by(x, q) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

All should give you the same result (although not in the same order). For example, the `data.table` output looks like this:

> ```
>    x q  y
> 1: a M  3
> 2: b M  7
> 3: c M 11
> 4: a W 15
> 5: b W 19
> 6: c W 23
> 7: a F 27
> 8: b F 31
> 9: c F 35
> ```